# How to add IDs for Tabs in Tabpanel in GWT?

Tags: gwt, dom

I am trying to set ids for tabs in the tabpanel. The code that I have written is:

```
Panel dateTab  = new VerticalPanel();
queryTabPanel.addTab("Date", dateTab);
```

where queryTabPanel is another TabPanel.

My Problem:  is to set Ids for the Tabs. So that I can click on the 'Date' tab in the tabpanel. 
What I have tried : is by manipulating DOM like :

```
DOM.setElementAttribute(productTab.getElement(), "id", "Swagatika");
```

But that does not seem to be working. :(

Has anyone any idea if that is possible, if so How difficult is to add IDs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know that's not what you're looking for but: why do you want to set an ID on the tab? what's your use case? there must be another way of achieving the same end result.

Comment: Why do I want to set Id : I have to assign Id to the tab, so that easily I can identify that element, with ID(though I am able to identify with CSSSelector, sometimes that becomes very complex.)
What's my Use Case : I am automating the application with Selenium WebDriver, as GWT assigns dynamic Ids, its not possible for Selenium to get the Ids and click, so if I can assign an ID to the tab, I can Click on that with Selenium easily.

Comment: Well, [ensureDebugId](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#ensureDebugId%28java.lang.String%29) is supposed to be the tool you're looking for. The first tab would then have an ID of `gwt-debug-theIdYouChose-bar-tab1' (see [TabPanel#onEnsureDebugId](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html#onEnsureDebugId%28java.lang.String%29))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing using WebDriver, you're supposed to use a special module that `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/>` (see "Renaming module" in [the GWT DevGuide](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml)), and call [ensureDebugId](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#ensureDebugId%28java.lang.String%29) on your widgets.

In your case, after calling `queryTabPanel.ensureDebugId("queryTabPanel")`, the first tab would have an ID of `gwt-debug-queryTabPanel-bar-tab1` (see [TabPanel.html#onEnsureDebugId](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html#onEnsureDebugId%28java.lang.String%29) for the details).

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, but I have read that the debug mode should be turned off in production.Is that true ? And if that is true, how can selenium run in production mode ?
Also can we not IDs to the Tab by DOM manipulation like how we add to other elements like Button, TextBox etc(This was actually my question)

Comment: You can leave `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/>` in your production app if you want; your users will just have to pay the performance price for assigning the IDs (can be negligible, maybe not). I think Google runs Selenium tests in "prod/web mode" (and possibly also in DevMode) on a dedicated server, where the app has been compiled with `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/>`.

Comment: Also could you tell me even after adding this why I am not getting IDs. I added <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/> to .gwt.xml to inherit the module. And queryTabPanel.ensureDebugId("queryTabPanel"). Is there something else need to be done to reflect this ?

Comment: As for doing DOM manipulations "by hand", that's indeed possible (use Firebug or similar to understand the DOM structure, there's a table, and each tab is wrapped in a div; and you should 'click' that div; something like `queryTabPanel.getTabBar().getElement().<TableElement>cast().getRows().getItem(0).getCells().getItem(i+1).getFirstChild().setId("foo")`) but a bit _fragile_ as you're dependent upon internal details of the widget (not that fragile actually, as it's unlikely to change; but switching to a DecoratedTabPanel for instance, or a TabLayoutPanel, would then be a breaking change).

Comment: Actually the queryTabPanel here is an DecoratedTabPanel and each tab is another VerticalPanel/Tabpanel.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Debug flag you need to use `TabLayoutPanel.getTabWidget(...)` and use `ensureDebugId` on it like the following:

```
    SimpleLayoutPanel newTabPanel = new SimpleLayoutPanel();
    tabLayoutPanel.add(newTabPanel, "Date Tab");
    tabLayoutPanel.getTabWidget(newTabPanel).ensureDebugId("MyDateTab");
```

Notice that setting the debug ID before adding the Widget to the tabLayoutPanel won't have any effect. Also make sure to use `getTabWidget(..)` and not `getWidget(...)`.